# How to fit SVG viewport to elements cointained, like default <div> behaviour?

Tags: svg

Slowly losing my sanity... I've tried every search term I can think of, but can't find anything about what would seem to be exceedingly simple.

**All I want is for the size, aka viewport, of my SVG to fit the containing elements.**

I specifically don't want it to scale, crop, meet, slice, zoom or anything else. I just want it to behave like a default div.

The SVG will then be placed inside a div with a max-height and overflow:auto.  When the SVG expands beyond the max-height of the containing div I will be able to scroll the div to see the whole of the SVG.